# Azure Cloud Service CPU max after upgrade from SDK 2.8 to 2.9

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

Just recently converted our 2.8 Azure Project to 2.9 and suddenly this started happening.

[image]

We're using a classic cloud service to host a web application. Don't understand why it suddenly starts to go bananas on the CPU load.

The process that seem to be using the CPU is called CollectGuestLogs.exe. Can I disable it somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We did open a ticket and found a solution to this issue:

*"Actually the CollectGuestlogs.exe is used by azure to generate the diagnostic log file and to zipped it.
This file exists in your PaaS VM instance in the below path 
D:\Packages\GuestAgent
First we have provided the temporary fix to confirm the issue like renaming the CollectGuestlogs.exe and check whether the process is running after restart the VM instance once.
As you confirmed that our temporary work around was successfully resolved your issue. We found that this issue is related to a known issue with the Azure SDK 2.9 that it is going to fixed in the hotfix release of Azure SDK version 2.9.5.1."* -Microsoft support